# Convergence Test of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried using Cauchy's root test but I'm stuck 
$$\sum\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\log^2n}$$
I thought about using comparison test also.
Thanks in advance

Comment: because $1/n\in(0,1]$ you can use a Taylor approximation for the sine around $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cauchy's condensation test, we get that that series converges if and only if

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n\sin(2^{-n})}{n^2\log^2 2}$$

converges.

Since $\sin(2^{-n})<2^{-n}$,

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n\sin(2^{-n})}{n^2\log^2 2}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2\log^2 2}<\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

use $$\sin (\frac {1}{n})\sim \frac {1}{n} \; (n\to \infty)$$

to obtain a Bertrand series

and compare it with the integral

$$\int_e^\infty \frac {1}{t\ln^2 (t)}dt $$

by putting $\ln (t)=x $.

Your series has the same nature than

$$\int_1^\infty \frac {dx}{x^2} $$

which is convergent.

Comment: Indeed we have that $0\le\sin(1/n)\le 1/n$ for $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$.